# leaflet.js ImageOverlay zoom changes marker position

Tags: javascript, leaflet, zooming

Am using ImageOverlay to use an image as a map, using Leaflet.js - but when changing the zoom the markers change position.

Have followed guideance in this [tutorial](http://kempe.net/blog/2014/06/14/leaflet-pan-zoom-image.html) and a code pen example is [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PRovvx).

```
// Markers 
var markers = [{"title":"OneOcean Port Vell","description":"Super yacht marina","link":"http:\/\/www.oneoceanportvell.com\/","x":"68.28125","y":"68.443002780352178"}]; 

var map = L.map('image-map', {
  minZoom: 2,
  maxZoom: 4,
  center: [0, 0],
  zoom: 2,
  attributionControl: false,
  maxBoundsViscosity: 1.0,
  crs: L.CRS.Simple
});

// dimensions of the image
var w = 3840,
    h = 2159,
    url = 'map.png';

// calculate the edges of the image, in coordinate space
var southWest = map.unproject([0, h], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var northEast = map.unproject([w, 0], map.getMaxZoom()-1);
var bounds = new L.LatLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

// add the image overlay, 
// so that it covers the entire map
L.imageOverlay(url, bounds).addTo(map);

// tell leaflet that the map is exactly as big as the image
map.setMaxBounds(bounds);

// Add Markers  
for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
    var marker = markers[i];

    // Convert Percentage position to point
    x = (marker['x']/100)*w;
    y = (marker['y']/100)*h;

    point = L.point((x / 2), (y / 2))
    latlng = map.unproject(point);

    L.marker(latlng).addTo(map);
}
```

In the codepen, change `zoom` to 4 to see the markers lose their position.

Ideally I'm trying to change the zoom to allow for different screen sizes and to get more of the map visible on mobile devices.

Also perhaps related, I can't see to get the [zoomSnap](http://leafletjs.com/examples/zoom-levels/) feature to work to allow for fractional zooming.

Any pointers greatly appriciated.

Comment: You know you should provide enough code to make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the _body_ of your question, not just relying on external services.

Comment: If you need help for `zoomSnap`, open a new question.

Comment: @ghybs apologies - have edited the question to add a barebones example.

Comment: @ghybs - thanks for the help, got zoomSnap working - just needed zoomDelta as well for the zoom controls to also be fractional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`map.unproject`](http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#map-unproject) needs the `zoom` value at which you want the un-projection to be applied.

You correctly specify your static `imageZoom` value to `unproject` when computing your `bounds` and `center`, but not for your markers positions.

If the `zoom` parameter is not specified, then `unproject` uses the current map zoom level, i.e. what you have defined in your `zoom` variable. That is why when you change its value, `unproject` for your markers uses a different value, and they are positioned in different locations.

You even had to divide your `x` and `y` values (relative to your image) by 2, to account for the fact that in your initial situation, they are correct for an `imageZoom` of 4, but since you do not specify the zoom for `unproject`, the latter uses the current `zoom` (i.e. 3), so coordinates should be divided by 2 to be "correct".

Updated codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pLvbvv